# How to modify this javascript highlight regex to not re-highlight itself?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regular-language, regexp-replace

I have this code:

```
display_title = 'Example text landscapes / more text';
// highlight landscapes
display_title = display_title.replace(/landscapes/gi,'<b>landscapes</b>');
// but also need to highlight some instances of "/"
display_title = display_title.replace(/\//gi,'<b>/</b>');
// ... more words to highlight
```

How should I modify the code so that the second highlight command would NOT replace the slash inside the `landscapes</b>` ? In other words, it should only match outside of html tags.

I found some examples but these were using jQuery, I want to do it with normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either match `landscapes` or a forward slash, then replace with the matched text surrounded by `<b>`:

```js
const display_title = 'landscapes /';
const result = display_title.replace(/landscapes|\//gi, '<b>$&</b>');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it would not work in my case because the two sample words (landscapes and /) are inside a larger loop of dynamic words to highlight, They are not static. I added some details.

Comment: Just put all the words to highlight into the regular expression, separated by `|` - just like how the `\/` was added to the regular expression

Comment: If you want to be able to do it concisely, make an array of words to highlight, then join by `|` and pass to `new RegExp`

Comment: Yes, that would work. I will give that a try. I am still curious of a regex to match outside of html tags if anyone wants to post that too.